# Adding zeros between every 2 elements of a matrix in matlab/octave

Tags: matrix, octave

I am interested in how can I add rows and columns of zeros in a matrix so that it looks like this:

```
              1 0 2 0 3
1 2 3         0 0 0 0 0
2 3 4  =>     2 0 3 0 4
5 4 3         0 0 0 0 0
              5 0 4 0 3
```

Actually I am interested in how can I do this efficiently, because walking the matrix and adding zeros takes a lot of time if you work with a big matrix.

Update:

Thank you very much.

Now I'm trying to replace the zeroes with the sum of their neighbors:

```
              1 0 2 0 3     1 3 2 5 3
1 2 3         0 0 0 0 0     3 8 5 12... and so on
2 3 4  =>     2 0 3 0 4 =>
5 4 3         0 0 0 0 0
              5 0 4 0 3
```

as you can see i'm considering all the 8 neighbors of an element, but again using for and walking the matrix slows me down quite a bit, is there a faster way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let your little matrix be called `m1`.  Then:

```
m2 = zeros(5)

m2(1:2:end,1:2:end) = m1(:,:)
```

Obviously this is hard-wired to your example, I'll leave it to you to generalise.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to do part 2 of the question. The first does the shifts explicitly, and the second uses conv2. The second way should be faster.

```
M=[1 2 3; 2 3 4 ; 5 4 3];

% this matrix (M expanded) has zeros inserted, but also an extra row and column of zeros
Mex = kron(M,[1 0 ; 0 0 ]); 

% The sum matrix is built from shifts of the original matrix
Msum = Mex + circshift(Mex,[1 0]) + ...
             circshift(Mex,[-1 0]) +...
             circshift(Mex,[0 -1]) + ...
             circshift(Mex,[0 1]) + ...
             circshift(Mex,[1 1]) + ...
             circshift(Mex,[-1 1]) + ...
             circshift(Mex,[1 -1]) + ...
             circshift(Mex,[-1 -1]);

% trim the extra line
Msum = Msum(1:end-1,1:end-1)


% another version, a bit more fancy:
MexTrimmed = Mex(1:end-1,1:end-1);
MsumV2 = conv2(MexTrimmed,ones(3),'same')
```

Output:

```
Msum =

1    3    2    5    3
3    8    5   12    7
2    5    3    7    4
7   14    7   14    7
5    9    4    7    3

MsumV2 =

1    3    2    5    3
3    8    5   12    7
2    5    3    7    4
7   14    7   14    7
5    9    4    7    3
```